Paragraph adds default padding to my content
I'd like to know why I get extra padding in my box if I add a paragraph inside my div. Whereas placing my content directly inside a div shows no padding by default.
Take for instance the code below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
div{border: 5px solid darkblue;}

</style>
</head>
<body >
<div>This box has no padding</div>
<div>
<p>This other box contains a paragraph and has intrinsic padding <p> </div>
</body>
</html> 

I'd like to understand why placing my content in a paragraph inside a div throws in some default padding and how I can remove this padding.

Paragraphs have default margin, divs do not.

p { padding: 0 } would remove all padding for paragraphs. or margin depending on the browser

@ITgoldman Nope - p {margin: 0;} This is why we use a CSS Reset in most cases.

Thanks for your response.  I already tried setting padding to 0 but it still does not remove the intrinsic padding. Increasing the padding property, however, increases the spacing around the content.

Nice. Setting the margin to 0 does the trick. @Paulie_D. Just one more question for clarity. Is this paragraph margin relative to the div?

No the margin of a paragraph is always the same and applied to through the user agent (default stylesheet of the browser). As such it is browser depending. There can also be things like margin collapse happening if multiple margins collide with each other. Overall this would be a good time to learn basics and start to learn how to use the dev console. Within the dev console you can see the computed layout that tells you everything. It shows for every element how larger margins, paddings, etc are and which styles apply and where those styles come from (incl user agent)

The issue here is the margin, not the padding, so you can set p{margin:0;}
To save you stress in the future just set the margin and padding of all HTML elements  to zero by using the universal selector *{ margin:0; padding:0; }

A CSS reset is very opinion based and surely does not save you from stress as it also removes all intended margins and paddings and need to be re added for every element where you need them such as the body
